# What is wrong with my python code? (Multiplication program)

Tags: python, multiplication

So I tried to make a multiplication game. So it kinda works, but when I put in the right answer, it types 'Wrong' two times... as well as if I put in the wrong answer.

```
import sys #imports sys
random1=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'] #makes a list with numbers 1-12
random2=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'] #makes another list with numbers 1-12

from random import choice #gets a random number
while True: #makes the following code run in a loop
    print "To exit this game type 'exit'" #prints stuff
    theyputinstuffhere = raw_input("What is " + choice(random2) + " times " + choice(random1) + "? ") #asks the user things like 1*5 or some other random stuff.


    if theyputinstuffhere == "exit": #if the user typed in 'exit' then exit the game
        print "Now exiting game!" #prints stuff
        sys.exit() #exits

    elif theyputinstuffhere == int(choice(random2))*int(choice(random1)): #if what i typed is right, print stuff (I think i messed up here!)
        print "Correct!" #print stuff
    else:
       print "Wrong!" #otherwise print stuff
```

I don't know what i did wrong HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!! QUICK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: when you call `choice(random2)` and `choice(random1)` again it gets a different number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work perfectly

```
import sys 
import random

while True: 
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(0,12)
    print "To exit this game type 'exit'" 
    theyputinstuffhere = raw_input("What is " + str(num2) + " times " + str(num1) + "? ") 


    if theyputinstuffhere == "exit": #if the user typed in 'exit' then exit the game
        print "Now exiting game!" #prints stuff
        sys.exit() #exits

    elif int(theyputinstuffhere) == num1*num2: 
        print "Correct!" #print stuff
    else:
        print "Wrong!"
```

use `random.randint` instead of choice cause then you dont need a list you were close though!

and you were reseting `num1` and `num2` when you were using youre if statement now it resets every loop

Comment: He means `raw_input` instead of `input`, but otherwise this is the right way to do it.

Comment: You're right-=with raw_input you'll have to add `int()` to the comparison.

Comment: I have been trying for the last like, WEEK and I still couldn't. So i came HERE for help, and I got some. Help which is helpful, but does not work 100%. It still helped tho...

Comment: ok i fixed it just type exit and it will exit there you go you should accept my answer if it worked too

Comment: But now with the raw_input it says wrong for the things that are supposed to be right, like 1*1=1 WRONG. It exits, but fails at math...

Comment: I copied everything letter by letter, word for word and sentence by sentence.

Comment: and yes it gives correct if correct and wrong if wrong re copy and paste the code

Comment: just re copy and paste it just to be safe

Comment: OOOOOHHHHHHHH!!!!!!! I JUST COPIED WRONG!!! THANKS CHRISTIAN!!! SORRY FOR BEING SUCH A DRAG!

Comment: all good everyone starts somewhere i new you just copied wrong and maybe next time try doing a google search and a little more trouble shooting before asking no problem though

Answer (score 1):

You are using choice twice, so while what you are asking could be something like this: 5 * 6
Your if statement could check for something like: 11 * 4
You are also comparing int to string, so convert your theyputinstuffhere to int in the conditional as well.

Also, choice() is a bad function for this, if you had used randrange() instead you wouldn't have to create a list at all. Try assigning both of your initial choice() return values to variables, and use those in both your prompt and conditional later.

Comment: also `raw_input` will give back a string so use `input` to get a int instead or use `int(theyputinstuffhere)` for the answer check and just use `theyputinstuffhere` for the exit

Comment: Please, I don't understand... could you, you know...just type the whole code out for me?

Comment: OMFG I StIlL nEeD hElP??!?!??!?!?!??!!??!?!?!

Comment: litterally copy and paste my answer @user2468523

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
theyputinstuffhere = raw_input("What is " + choice(random2) + " times " + choice(random1) + "? ") #asks the user things like 1*5 or some other random stuff.


if theyputinstuffhere == "exit": #if the user typed in 'exit' then exit the game
    print "Now exiting game!" #prints stuff
    sys.exit() #exits

elif int(theyputinstuffhere) == int(choice(random2))*int(choice(random1)): #if what i typed is right, print stuff (I think i messed up here!)
    print "Correct!" #print stuff
else:
   print "Wrong!" #otherwise print stuff
```

do this:

```
num1 = choice(random1)
num2 = choice(random2)
theyputinstuffhere = raw_input("What is " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "? ") #asks the user things like 1*5 or some other random stuff.


if theyputinstuffhere == "exit": #if the user typed in 'exit' then exit the game
    print "Now exiting game!" #prints stuff
    sys.exit() #exits

elif theyputinstuffhere == int(num1)*int(num2): #if what i typed is right, print stuff (I think i messed up here!)
    print "Correct!" #print stuff
else:
   print "Wrong!" #otherwise print stuff
```

Comment: Thanks stackErr, but this does not work...it gives me this:To exit this game type 'exit'
    What is 5 times 7? 35
    Wrong!
    To exit this game type 'exit'
    What is 5 times 7? 2
    Wrong!
    To exit this game type 'exit'
    What is 5 times 7? 35
    Wrong!
    To exit this game type 'exit'
    What is 5 times 7?

Comment: To exit this game type 'exit'

Comment: Wrong! #(this is just here cuz...)

Comment: Then it says the same stuff, except now it says: What is 6 times 2?

Comment: I dont understand your last 2-3 comments, can you explain what happens again, in a single comment.

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION IS >>>>>> ANSWERED BY CHRISTIAN CAREAGA !!!!!

```
import sys 
import random

while True: 
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(0,12)
    print "To exit this game type 'exit'" 
    theyputinstuffhere = raw_input("What is " + str(num2) + " times " + str(num1) + "? ") 


if theyputinstuffhere == "exit": #if the user typed in 'exit' then exit the game
    print "Now exiting game!" #prints stuff
    sys.exit() #exits

elif int(theyputinstuffhere) == num1*num2: 
    print "Correct!" #print stuff
else:
    print "Wrong!"
```

THANK YOU ALL!!!! YOU ALL HELPED!!! (Sorry Christian, i just copied wrong...)